# Symfony 3 route not found

Tags: routes, symfony

Attempting to follow the Symfony 3.1 book:

Here is my controller

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction() {
        $num = rand(0,100);
        return new Response("number is ".  $num);
    }
}
```

The book goes to the url: http://localhost:8000/lucky/number
to see the response. However, for me this ends in a 404 `The requested resource /lucky/number was not found on this server.`.

From reading a few other similar questions it looks like the routing can be done through annotations. What is wrong with this code here?

edit: regarding web server: I'm running the built in php server from the web/ directory. i.e. `php -S localhost:8000`. Also ran with `php bin/console server:run` - sends back `No route found for "GET /lucky/number`

Comment: Did you cut & paste that code? If not, check if you have a tab in `* @Route` or not and change to a space. If not, did you run `php bin/console server:run` from the command line?

Comment: didn't cut and paste. Also ran with 'php bin/console server:run' - still sends back "No route found for "GET /lucky/number". It's a space between * @Route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the _locale, and en for english.

Check the files:

```
app/config/routing.yml
app/config/config.yml
```

See this reference:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's another possible problem here, and that's the existance of a cache. If you are following the tutorial, you probably already viewed the first page, and thus Symfony cached the classes and routes. 
To make sure Symfony picks up these changes, make sure to clear the cache (with the proper environment parameter):

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution from another question that I did not find prior to asking the question.

Looks like the book has a typo and the route to go to is `http://localhost:8000/en/lucky/number`.

All works well if you do that. I'm not sure where the /en/ route part is defined though.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact problem on Symfony 3.2 and solved it doing

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`
every time i nedd to test new added routes.

Thks.